# Swift 2 - Variável com valor nulo

Tags: swift

Tenho uma página web que retorna a seguinte estrutura json:

```
[  
   {  
      "nomeDoServico":"fdPHost",
      "nomeParaExibicao":"Host de Provedor da Descoberta de Função",
      "status":"Iniciado"
   },
   {  
      "nomeDoServico":"LanmanWorkstation",
      "nomeParaExibicao":"Estação de trabalho",
      "status":"Iniciado"
   }
]
```

O código abaixo escrito em Swift 2 deveria pegar este retorno e por hora preencher a tableView com somente o valor nomeDoServico. Porém, quando dou um print vejo que a função **consultarServiço** não conseguiu popular a variável **valores**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var valores = [Dictionary<String, String>]()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return valores.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let valor = valores[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = valor["nomeDoServico"]
        return cell
    }

    func consultarServico() -> Void
    {
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.56.101/database_servico.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!)

        let postString:String = "id_menu=1"
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval = 5.0

        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

            if (error?.code == -1001)
            {
                print("Opa, timeout")
            }

            do {
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
                self.valores = jsonResult
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Erro ao buscar os dados")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ocultar teclado ao clicar na view
        let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        consultarServico()
    }

    // encerra o teclado
    func DismissKeyboard(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Você já verificou o que vem no `response`?

Comment: Tente em vez de colocar numa let, chamar o valores[indexPath.row] direto na string da celula

Comment: Já tentei isso, mas o problema é que não estou conseguindo na verdade preencher a variável "valores" com o retorno do json. Acho que seria mais correto falar que não estou conseguindo pegar o callback.

Comment: O json está sendo retornado, já testei e o retorno é o que passei no primeiro bloco de código. Mas não estou conseguindo jogar este retorno para dentro da variável "valores".

Comment: Quando você passa `self.valores = jsonResult`, esta passando um objeto imutável para o um objeto mutável, tente criar um novo objeto recebendo como base o `jsonResult` utilizando o método [initWithDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/initWithDictionary:)

Comment: Pois é amigo, já tentei varias alternativas mas nada funciona. Pelo que pude ver não consigo pegar o json retornado dentro da clousure "closure" e chorar em uma variável externa a mesma.

Comment: Você consegue publicar essa url em algum lugar para que eu possa simular?

Comment: Publiquei um similar do json que estou utilizando no endereço: http://fabiojanio.com/json/json.php

Comment: Fábio, aqui não marcamos a pergunta como resolvida no título, basta aceitar uma resposta como você já fez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testei aqui com o seu código e o retorno é salvo na variável normalmente.

Você precisa só mudar alguns pontos.

**1)** O seu `json` é um `array` e não uma `dicionary`, altere para:

> var valores: NSArray = []

**2)** Quando receber os dados na requisição mude para:

> let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

**3)** Dê um `reload` na tabela assim que pegar os dados:

> self.tableView.reloadData()

**4)** No `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` altere para:

> let valor = valores[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
>
> cell.textLabel?.text = valor["nomeDoServico"] as? String

---

**Segue o código completo**

```
class TesteViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
        
    var valores: NSArray = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView : UITableView!
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return valores.count
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let valor = valores[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        cell.textLabel?.text = valor["nomeDoServico"] as? String
        return cell
    }
    
    func consultarServico() -> Void
    {
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://fabiojanio.com/json/json.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!)
        
        let postString:String = "id_menu=1"
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval = 5.0
        
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if (error?.code == -1001)
            {
                print("Opa, timeout")
            }
            
            do {
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
                
                self.valores = jsonResult
                
                self.performSelectorOnMainThread(Selector("atualizaTabela"), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Erro ao buscar os dados")
            }
        }
        
        
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func atualizaTabela(){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // ocultar teclado ao clicar na view
        let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        
        consultarServico()
    }
    
    // encerra o teclado
    func DismissKeyboard(){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa, show de bola. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Só achei estranho uma coisa, quando clico na tabela tenho uma atualização imediata da mesma, porém, se esperar geralmente leva mais de 7 segundos para que os valores sejam apresentados. Sabe o que seria?

Comment: Notei essa demora mesmo, não vou saber te dizer qual é o real motivo, provavelmente pq esta terminar a `thread`, editei a resposta dando um `performSelectorOnMainThread` e aparentemente ficou atualizando certo agora

Comment: Agora ficou perfeito. Este era meu maior problema, mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda.

Agora estou pesquisando para saber como customizar aquela prototype Cell, quero colocar uma label lá para o serviço e outra para o status, itens estes que são os valores retornados no json.

Comment: Que isso, estamos aqui para sempre ajudar, da um upvote e marque como resposta escolhido caso tenha ajudado no seu problema, boa sorte nas pesquisas, qualquer problema pode criar uma nova pergunta

Comment: Aconselho a usar frameworks para conexão, depois da uma pesquisada sobre AFNetworking ou Alamofire